# Add new reply in list after submit without reload in vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I am new to Vue and trying to make a blog project.
[image]

In above image when i click on reply button a dialog box opens and i submit a reply to the comment.

But the problem here is that After submitting the form and on ***dialog=false*** the new submitted reply doesn't show in the list.

my code is

```
<v-btn
  @click="handleReply(comment.id)"
 >Reply</v-btn>

<v-dialog v-model="dialog" max-width="400">
            <v-card>
              <v-card-title>
                <span class="headline">{{ formTitle }}</span>
              </v-card-title>
              <v-card-text>
                <v-form ref="replyForm" v-model="isFormValid" lazy-validation>
                  <v-text-field v-model="editedReply.reply" label="reply" required></v-text-field>
                </v-form>
              </v-card-text>

              <v-card-actions>
                <v-spacer></v-spacer>
                <v-btn color="primary" text @click="close">Cancel</v-btn>
                <v-btn
                  color="primary"
                  @click.prevent="handleSubmit"
                  :disabled="!isFormValid || isProcessing"
                  :loading="isProcessing"
                >Save</v-btn>
              </v-card-actions>
            </v-card>
          </v-dialog>
```

and

```
handleReply(id) {
      this.dialog = true;
      this.editedReply.comment_id = id;
    },    
handleSubmit() {
       this.isProcessing = true;
       axios
          .post(`/replies`, { reply: this.editedReply })
          .then(res => {
          this.isProcessing = false;
          const newEntry = res.data.reply;
          this.replies.push(newEntry);
          this.dialog = false;
},
```

Here `this.editedReply` presents the state of all params which are

```
editedReply: {
    reply: null,
    comment_id: null,
    name: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user")).name,
    email: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user")).email
}
```

we are getting comment id from `handleReply` method.

thanks:)

Comment: Please create a [small demo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for this using [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue) to show the issue happening. No need to add the whole code in the demo, just the part where submit is resulting in the page reload. See if you can reproduce the issue with minimal code.

Comment: Where does the list of replies come from? All you should need to do is push the new reply to that collection

Comment: @Phil I am getting list of all replies from `getReplies()` methode and saving the reply collection in `replies: []`  and as you can see i am pushing the new reply as you can see in handleSubmit() methode line 7 in my question. but it is not reloading list

Comment: this.replies.push(newEntry); can you put console.log after this line, If you get the new reply form api response, it should update else this is a data reactivity issue. Please share your observation, we are there to help you

Comment: Where is `replies` defined?

Comment: @Phil  I have added the code here  https://jsfiddle.net/dhruvildave22/501xpsu3/1/

Comment: Please add it to your question above